# How to deal with a npm package whose AOT compilation fails

Tags: angular, npm, angular-compiler-cli, angular-aot

I am a complete newbee to web development, and now I am facing a problem that I do not know how to deal with.

I am using the npm package named `@uniprank/ngx-file-uploader` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uniprank/ngx-file-uploader) in my web application. When compiling it with JIT compilation it works with no problems. However, now I would like to turn my application to production mode, so I tried AOT compilation, and a problem is found. This package breaks when I try to compile my application with the Angular compiler, as it is shown here: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler. The message shown is the following:

```
Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'FileUploaderModule in /node_modules/@uniprank/ngx-file-uploader/typings/index.d.ts'
```

In one of the issues of the Github repository of the package (https://github.com/uniprank/ngx-file-uploader/issues/3), I noticed that this may be a problem of the package itself.

I am completely lost at this point. I know this is a very generic question, but I do not know how to deal with this problem. Should I work on the package itself? And if so, would I have to create a new npm package to add it to my `package.json` and to include it in my application when executing the command `npm install`?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can fix problem in 3rd party package then do pull request to this repo.
Or you can fork this repo and fix problem in your own. And then include in package.json link to your repo. for example: your repo name `user/package` then you can write `npm install user/package`

Comment: Thanks. That is the way to go. It was difficult for me to fix the package, so I changed to another one whose AOT compilation works like a charm.